# ConfigurationException: Unrecognized strategy option {datacenter1} passed to SimpleStrategy for keyspace cycling

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am total beginner with Cassandra.I have tried this

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE cycling
   ... WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1 };
```

But datacenter1 is not recognized

```
ConfigurationException: Unrecognized strategy option {datacenter1} passed to SimpleStrategy for keyspace cycling
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SimpleStrategy` doesn't support that option. The correct create statement would be:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cycling WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};
```

If you want to specify replication by datacenter then you need to use the `NetworkTopologyStrategy`, in which case the create statement would be:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cycling WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','datacenter1':1};
```

More information on this can be found [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateKeyspace.html)